# How does system verilog treat if statements in always_ff blocks

Tags: fpga, system-verilog, intel-fpga

```
always_ff @(posedge sysclk) begin
case(state) begin
  SOME_STATE begin
    if(some logic to check) begin
       variable1 <= 1;
       variable2 <= variable_a > 0 ? 0 : 1;
       end
    else begin
       variable1 <= variable_b > 0 ? 0 : 1;
       variable2 <= 1;
       end
    variable3 <= {variable1, variable2}; 
    end //this case
  endcase
end //always_ff
```

All variables are of type logic and are appropriately sized.

Will system verilog correctly evaluate the statements controlling var1 and 2 before assigning them into var3 or does it treat if statements within an always_ff as non-blocking?  There're more else if's that have been removed for clarity of the question.

Answer (score 1):

A *non-blocking assignment* within an `always_ff` block infers a flip-flop. An `if` statement is irrelevant. So, in your example code, `variable1`, `variable2` and `variable3` will all behave like flip-flops in simulation and hence will become flip-flops after synthesis.

If you would prefer `variable1` and `variable2` to be combinational logic then you must use *blocking assignments*:

```
always_ff @(posedge sysclk) begin
case(state) begin
  SOME_STATE begin
    if(some logic to check) begin
       variable1 = 1;                           // <-----
       variable2 = variable_a > 0 ? 0 : 1;      // <-----
       end
    else begin
       variable1 = variable_b > 0 ? 0 : 1;      // <-----
       variable2 = 1;                           // <-----
       end
    variable3 <= {variable1, variable2}; 
    end //this case
  endcase
end //always_ff
```

If you want this then I would recommend you *declare* `variable1` and `variable2` inside the `begin`-`end` block:

```
always_ff @(posedge sysclk) begin
<some type> variable1;                          // <-----
<some type> variable2;                          // <-----
case(state) begin
    ...
    variable3 <= {variable1, variable2}; 
    end //this case
  endcase
end //always_ff
```

That will prevent any other `always` block from being able to see these variables, which will prevent the potential *simulation races* that would occur if some other `always` block could see them.

Answer (score 0):

The IF statement will represent the Boolean logic that will drive the value to your flops.

I would rather split the combinational logic in an always_comb process and the sequential logic in the always_ff.

```
always_ff @(posedge sysclk) begin
   if (something)
    variable1 <= value; // Non Blocking assignment in always_ff block, variable 1 will be a Flip-Flop
end //always_ff


always_comb begin
   if (something)
    variable2 = value; // Non Blocking assignment in always_comb block, variable2 won't be a flop in this case, but just a combinatinal logic.
end //always_comb
```

Your IF statement will infer the same logic, in both the always_ff and always_comb block the inferred logic will act as an enable to load the value into variable1.

I hope it clarify what you are asking.